# Seeking Advice on Enhancing Security Measures for My React Native Money Game

Tags: react-native, root, asyncstorage, data-protection

I have developed a money game using React Native, and I'm facing a security concern. In my game, I have two variables: 'score' and 'increment'. The score is initially set to 10, and every three seconds, the score is incremented by the value of the 'increment' variable. For example, if the increment is 3, the score will be 13 after three seconds and 16 after another three seconds.
However, a friend of mine with a rooted device was able to access the AsyncStorage data of my game and change the values, effectively hacking my game. I'm looking for advice on how to protect my game against such unauthorized modifications.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or best practices to enhance the security of my game and prevent unauthorized access to the AsyncStorage data. Thank you in advance for your assistance!"

Comment: Check out [Android secure storage](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://android.googlesource.com/trusty/app/storage/%2B/refs/heads/master/README.md&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwilzviw3cSAAxX_hu4BHRGZC2UQFnoECAwQBg&usg=AOvVaw24GeA1gOG4Pdrxfvle5Q1-)

Comment: @Abe does Android secure storage work in React Native

Comment: Pretty sure there are already packages for it if you look

Comment: If not, good chance to write some native code

Comment: what are the packages for it. please give me the packages that compatible with react native 0.72

Comment: @Abe what are the packages for it. please give me the packages that compatible with react native 0.72 –

Comment: I am trying to get you to look for the solution yourself. 1. Asking for packages is not generally allowed on SO. 2. A 5-second Google for "Android secure store React Native" is going help a lot more than messaging a random person on SO. Best of luck